# Excel sheet is not opening in ASP.NET application after deploying

Tags: asp.net, excel

HI,
I have deployed an Asp.Net 2.0 application in IIS.In this, I have folder(uploads) which contains a temp file.In the page, i have once button(Display),when i click on the display button, the excel sheet should be opened.This is happening in local but not after deploying in IIS. It showing the error message like "Microsoft Office Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space".

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks
Rupa

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is enough available memory or disk space?

Comment: Is the "display" button a direct link or an asp.net control?

Comment: when you say an excel spreadsheet should open, do you mean the user should be prompted to save or open the file?  Are you creating the spreadsheet in code?

Comment: put other format of file in your temp folder, then check if it will be  open, like put word document to check if it is open or getting the same message.

Answer (score 1):

for that try spread Sheet Gear third party component
http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/

Plus you can check this thread if this is help for you
[ASP.NET manuplating Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931782/asp-net-manuplating-excel-sheet/931885#931885)

Comment: I did something like what you are doing, and got the same error message, then I have use spreadsheet gear, that's why I have advise you